# Does meta http-equiv="Refresh" execute code on the page before directing to another URL?

Tags: html

If pageA.php has the following line of code in the  section:

```
 meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;url=pageB.php"
```

When pageA.php refreshes, does it execute again (i.e. will any PHP scripts on pageA run again) before going to pageB.php, or does it go directly to pageB.php?

I've looked around, but can't find an answer.

Thx.

Comment: Depends .... if paegA.php has expiry headers set, then the browser will probably not fetch/execute it again when you reload, unless you do CTRL-F5 to circumvent the client cache.  Just as with any regular HTML document.  If pageA.php has no expiry headers, then yes, the page will be fetched by the browser and as such, will be executed on the server again, before the browser "sees" the meta tag and performs a redirection to pageB.php.

Comment: going "back" to page A would reset the refresh counter, meaning you'd never ever reach pageB, you'd just keep looping on pageA.

Answer (score 0):

It will go directly to pageB. If it re-executed pageA, how would it ever end?